# unable to configure Tika1.2 with solr4

Tags: solr, apache-tika, dataimporthandler, solr4

I am trying to use TikaEntityProcessor to index the .html file content. Somehow I am not able to get it correctly. I have checked the error log and I got the following error.

```
SEVERE: Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:tika-test Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:382)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:448)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:429)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:tika-test Processing Document # 1
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:71)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:697)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:703)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:215)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load TikaEntityProcessor or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:899)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:694)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'TikaEntityProcessor'
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:436)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:889)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TikaEntityProcessor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
```

My data-config.xml file is as follow:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
    <entity name="f" processor="FileListEntityProcessor" baseDir="path/to/basedir/" fileName=".*html" recursive="true" rootEntity="true" dataSource="null">
       <entity name="tika-test" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" url="path/tohtml/files/" format="text" onError="skip">
            <field column="product_id" name="product_id" meta="true"/>
            <field column="type" name="type" meta="true"/>
            <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>        
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

I have added following code in solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport"  class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="config">/path/to/data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
```

I have kept the default schema.xml file and added the following code in that file.

```
<field name="product_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

can anyone please tell me what am I missing here? or why I am get the errors? and what's it's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jars (or paths) for apache-solr-dataimporthandler-4.0, apache-solr-dataimporthandler- extras-4.0 and apache-solr-cell-4.o in the dist folder as well as corresponding files in the contrib folder.

that's how my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add *lib* directives in solrconfig.xml to make sure that tika libraries are loaded? You need (I believe):

```
<lib dir="${user.dir}/../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="${user.dir}/../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

If you are using Solr 4, not Solr 4.1, you may need to say apache-solr-cell.... instead of just solr-cell...

Comment: yes I have added those lib directory to solrconfig.xml file. it looks like: 

`<lib dir="../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../dist/" regex="apache-solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />`

Comment: Are you sure your ".." is based on correct location? Are you starting this from solr example directory with custom solr.solr.home? Have a look at system monitoring tools to see whether those jars are found and loaded (ProcessMonitor on Windows, dtrace and derivates on Unix/Mac)

Comment: yes I have checked that ".." works for me. Yes I have started from solr example directory but I have changed the solr home directory. It's now solr.home instead of solr.solr.home.

Answer (score 1):

TikaEntityProcessor is available in the [dataimporthandler-extras](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/solr/solr-dataimporthandler-extras/3.5.0/solr-dataimporthandler-extras-3.5.0-javadoc.jar!/index.html) jar file.
you can use `apache-solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar` pattern to load the file.

Comment: I have already added these two pattern in my solrconfig.xml file. `<lib dir="../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" /> <lib dir="../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />` but still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: I have configured Tika and solr.But I have another problem and for that I have post new [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005919/how-to-extract-metatags-from-html-files-and-index-them-in-solr-and-tika) can you please look that and give me suggestion.