# Indexing documents with websolr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr, lucene, websolr

We're looking at using the Websolr add-on for searching Resources within our Rails app.

The app contains many Resource models. Most of the resource models are self-contained, with a series of attributes: author, title, a set of tags etc, however some of the Resource models have a pdf attached. We need to index the content of this pdf so that it is searchable as a part of the Resource.

How should I approach this?

Comment: may be this question will be your [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815771/unable-to-configure-tika1-2-with-solr4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started: [ExtractingRequestHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler), which integrates [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) into Solr.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. Have you had any experience of doing this using Rails and Websolr? Is it definitely possible?

Comment: No, I have no Rails/WebSolr experience, which is why my answer was so short :-). Googled and found http://johntwang.com/blog/2011/09/05/Fuzzy-and-Document-Searching-with-WebSolr-and-Heroku/ and https://github.com/chebyte/sunspot_cell.

Comment: We do support Solr Cell at Websolr — client integration can definitely vary from platform to platform.