# How to index html files in apache slor using DIH

Tags: html, apache, solr, dih

I am new to apache solr and trying to index html files in apche solr using DIH.can someone help me out with proper direction.

Comment: thanks  for the link...i have already done some basic exercise on Indexing with apache solr...Now in perticular i was looking for  indexing html files using DIH on apache solr...any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have did this using the nutch and solr. you need to install nutch and and configure with solr. I have asked this question already but didn't got the solution and I have figure out by myself.

for reference here is the link of my question.

[How can I do indexing .html files in SOLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711415/how-can-i-do-indexing-html-files-in-solr)

Comment: Hi Anand,Thanks for your help...can you share  a document on that if you have already done that...it will be great!!

Comment: I don't have any physical document with me but If you have any specific question let me know I can help you out if I know that.